# Can't Set Spinner Alignment

Tags: android, alignment, spinner

I can't set spinner alignment. I want to same alignment with textView12. I tried textAlignment but it didn't work. Any idea?

main.xml

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="@string/tekrar"
    android:id="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bolme4saat"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView10"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:textAlignment="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"/>
```

[Design picture in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEdpJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[android:textAlignment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:textAlignment) doesn't use ids. Instead you should use android:layout_alignStart (and android:layout_alignLeft if your minimal sdk version is below 17) to "@+id/textView12" similiar to what you've done with the TextView.

So

```
android:textAlignment="@+id/textView12"
```

becomes

```
android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView12"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView12"
```

Comment: but my minimal sdk version 19, and it didn't work :(

Comment: for mentioned setting you need to use RelativeLayout

Comment: android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textView3" is the solution. Thanks guys